# Laravel 5.4 not working on PHP 7.0 due to Doctrine package

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, php-7

I'm trying to deploy a Laravel application on an AWS PHP 7.0 instance (Elastic Beanstalk, but that doesn't really matter).

I get the following error

```
+ composer.phar install --no-ansi --no-interaction
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/instantiator[1.1.0].
    - doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects 3.4.4 requires doctrine/instantiator ^1.0.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/instantiator[1.1.0].
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects 3.4.4 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects[3.4.4].
 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

Any ideas how can I suppress this or get around it on PHP 7.0?

My composer.json

```
{
    "name": "myapp",
    "description": "My App.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel", "lumen"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.4.*",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2",
        "romanpitak/nginx-config-processor": "^0.2.1",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "^3.2",
        "comodojo/zip": "^2.1",
        "riimu/kit-pathjoin": "1.*",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.25",
        "spatie/url": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "~0.9"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/",
            "database/"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

P.s. I am not using any unit testing. I tried to get rid of the "require-dev" packages and still the same error.

Comment: Why are you deploying development dependencies? Is this a test environment? If not, run `composer install --no-dev`. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install.

Comment: It looks to me like you're not getting rid of your composer.lock file between each change to composer.json? `composer install` doesn't look at composer.json if a composer.lock file is present, does it? The clue is that you say you've got rid of yer phpunit dependency from composer.json, but it's still being mentioned in the "error" message (indirectly).

Answer (score 1):

The bug was that "composer.lock" existed, what happens when we run "composer install" in that case?

*It’s time to run composer install again. This time, Composer will see that you have a composer.lock file in the directory. Instead, of finding compatible versions of your dependencies to fulfil the composer.json file, it will install the exact version of your dependencies as defined in your composer.lock file.* (https://laravel-news.com/understanding-the-composer-lock-file)